# How to parse Json using Regex?

Tags: regex, json, parsing, regular-language

I want to parse this json data with regex. But, i could not.
I tried like this `module.getid(.*)`, but no working.

Only, I want to take this part -> `module.getid(...)`

```
module.getid([{"id":"44423"}]); module.getresult([{"result":"false"}]);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You can't parse json with a regex since [it's not a regular language](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) - why would you want to use a regex instead of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to extract `[{"id":"44423"}]` from the sample he provided. Anyway, _no working_ is rather vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to capture the first ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN3iA0)):

```
/module.getid\((.*?)\); *module.getresult(?:.*?)\);$/m
```

If you want to capture both *json* strings ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/qO4iY9)):

```
/module.getid\((.*?)\); *module.getresult(.*?)\);$/m
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really clean and easy solution. Are there another way?

Comment: What about matching only the ID's value? For example, say we have this instead: `module.getid([{"id":"44423", "code":"mod_editor"}]);`. How would I use a single regex to return, in this example, just `44423`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to work from that new string you gave us:

> module.getid([{"id":"44423", "code":"mod_editor"}]);

Here's a regular expression that nicely compartmentalizes all the data from the line provided

`m/module\x2egetid\x28\x5b\x7b\x22(?<key1>[^\x22]+)\x22\x3a\x22(?<value1>\d+)\x22\x2c\s+\x22(?<key2>[^\x22]+)\x22\x3a\x22(?<value2>[^\x22]+)\x22/`

You can reference the fields by using the named captures or the number of the capture, whichever you prefer.

in this case to just return the portion of data which in this string is 44423 you could either reference capture number '2' or capture name 'value1'.

I'm not sure which language you're using to 'parse' this data, so I couldn't give you an actual snippet of working code.

Comment: That might work, still I'd say a JSON.parse approach would be a lot better!

Comment: While I agree that using a JSON parser would be a much better approach, I felt that just in case there was a reason to not use a JSON parser I would answer the question at face value.